# WooCommerce Api returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working on a get method to retrieve products from a Woo-commerce store, the code is supposed to return a Json with all the products but instead of that its returning a large Html. It only happens when I send the get request to my clients wordpress URL. When I run the test on my local woocommerce instance it works.[This is a screenshot of the response when i do the request to my clients URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOAXE.jpg)

And [this is a screenshot of the response of my woocommerce test shop running on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuD8U.png)

Comment: Maybe if you show the get request someone could help you?

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like you are using the wrong url to your client's website because you get a 404 page. What does your request look like?